# File I/O, Creation of Path with Constructor Variable

Tags: java, file, io, path

How to create a path & file using the constructor variables

I am writing a simple logging application for my school. When I initialize the name variable for the logging the application works without a problem.

However, when I create an instance with a different name given in the constructor, the program goes to the instance variable to create a null logging file before creating the new logging file.

Also when I rerun the application it always gives an exception the file has already been found, but as far as I can see this should be resolved in a loop in my code.

I feel I am missing something about Path mechanics or something else but I can't figure it out.

```
private String name;
private int logLevel;
private Path path = checkPreviousVersions();


protected FlexibleLogger(String name,int logLevel) throws IOException {
    this.logLevel = logLevel;
    this.name=name;
        }

public Path checkPreviousVersions() throws IOException{

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fresults = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = new File("./logs").listFiles();

    for (File file: files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            results.add(file.getName());
        }
    }

    for (String result: results){
        fresults.add(result.replace(result,result.substring(0,result.indexOf("."))));
    }

    if (fresults.contains(name)) {
        Path mypath = Paths.get("./logs/" + name + ".log");
        String s = "=======================" + dateFormatter() + "=======================" + "\n";
        writeToFile(s);
        return mypath;


    } else {
        Path mypath = Paths.get("./logs/" + name + ".log");
        Files.createFile(mypath);
        return mypath;

    }

}
```

The expected result is one file for the first creation and a new file every time the name is changed. If the name is not changed it should update the existing file.

The actual result is the creation of two files, one "null" and one with the constructor name variable. On a second loop with the same name, it gives "FileAlreadyExists" error.

Thank you kindly for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like too much code for such logic. No need to get all files in directory.

Here's the easy way:
- create new File("./logs", name) 
- check if file exists: if (file.exists())
- if it doesn't exist, create it 
- append your text to it

That's it.